# How to set a fixed height of another component for a Prime Ng Tree using Prime Flex

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I have a Prime Ng Tree in my html in a grid with 3 columns. The first column is the Tree, the second column is a textarea with 20 rows, so that the row expands to fill that size. When I expand items in the Tree, it grows beyond the size of the text area and so the row expands even further. Is it possible to set the max height of the tree to the height of the text box (and then enable scroll on the tree)?

Here is the html:

```
<div class="grid">

    <div class="col-3">

        <p-contextMenu #contextMenu [model]="contextMenuItems"></p-contextMenu>
        <p-tree [value]="connectionMenu" class="w-full md:w-30rem h-full" selectionMode="single" [contextMenu]="contextMenu" [(selection)]="selectedNode" (onNodeContextMenuSelect)="getMenuItems($event, contextMenu)"></p-tree>

    </div>
    <div class="col-6">

        <textarea rows="20" class="w-full" pInputTextarea [(ngModel)]="program"></textarea>  

    </div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
```

I cant find the relevant Prime Css/Prime Flex documentation to figure this out, and my CSS skills are poor.